# Assigning group up on registration — Laravel, Fortify

Tags: laravel

I'm pretty new at Laravel and I'm making an e-commerce website, however, I'd like to make it so there are 2 types of registration — one for regular users and one for another type of users. What I'd like to do is to be able to assign a certain group to a user when they use the 'other' registration. Basically, I have the regular registration set up so it assigns a 'USER' group to the user upon registration, and now what I'm trying to do is set up another registration that'd give them another role as a default value.
Any ideas how I can effect this?

Comment: Well you can basically just assign him new role upon 2nd registration. I'm not sure what you wanna try to achive here

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. I wanna have a regular registration (DB group: USER) and registration for sellers (DB group: SELLER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you need to create user_type migration and then user migration. User will belongs to user_type as on example below:

User Type migraton:

```
Schema::create('user_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->string('type');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Users migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    
    $table->foreignId('user_type_id')->constrained(); //declare user type
    
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Users model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function type(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserType::class);
    }
}
```

UserType model:

```
class UserType extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public const USER   = 1;
    public const SELLER = 2;

    public function user(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Type seeder:

```
class UserTypeSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        UserType::create(['id' => 1, 'type' => 'user']);
        UserType::create(['id' => 2, 'type' => 'seller']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your input. I have this done, a little bit different, but it works just fine! 
I use fortify and I have it set up so that when a user registers using the "/register" route it gives him a "user" role — I have it set as a default value in UserMigration. 
I also have a middleware (sanctum) checking the user's user groups (whether he's an admin/user or a seller), however, what I'm trying to do is to set up another registration (separately from the original one, that'd only allow SELLERS to register from it — subsequently gives out SELLER usergroup).

Comment: In short, what I wanna do is make another registration/find a way around to work this out so that when a user clicks on "Seller registration" and registers from it it'll give him a Seller role, because right now I only have the regular registration and it only gives out the "USER" role.

Comment: Well just make one more end-point. Route::get('/register-seller'); And on controller just register user with that details and give him seller role :)

Answer (score 0):

You must first define guards ( Seller) in config\ auth.php And then modify FortifyServiceProvider

in register add code

...

```
if (request() ->is('seller/*')){
            config(['fortify.features' => [
                Features::registration(),
                Features::resetPasswords(),
                Features::updatePasswords(),
            ]]);

            config(['fortify.prefix' => 'seller']);
            config(['fortify.home' => '/seller/dashboard']);
            config(['fortify.redirects.login' => '/seller/dashboard']);
            config(['fortify.redirects.logout' => '/seller']);
}
```

...

and in boot
add

```
if (request()->is('seller', 'seller/*')) {
    Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewSeller::class);
    Fortify::loginView('seller.auth.login');
    Fortify::registerView('seller.auth.register');
    Fortify::verifyEmailView('seller.auth.verify-email');
    Fortify::requestPasswordResetLinkView('seller.auth.forgot-password');
    Fortify::resetPasswordView('seller.auth.reset-password');
}
```

Don't forget to create new class(CreateNewSeller) in action folder implements from CreatesNewUsers